# Kaminari support blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Kaminari is great to create Twitter-like pagination:

```
=link_to_next_page(@results, t('kaminari.next'), :remote => true, :class => 'kaminari-next', :rel => 'next')
```

However, anyone has any idea to make it support blocks? I'd like to add a font-awesome icon:

```
 =link_to_next_page @results, :rel => 'next', :remote => true, :class => 'kaminari-next' do
    %i.icon-chevron-down.icon-2x
    %br
    =raw(t 'kaminari.next')
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the definition of the method by looking at the [source code of Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/d63ac017a9d115879e3c68684911cc7dea86c025/lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb).

```
# A simple "Twitter like" pagination link that creates a link to the next page.
#
# ==== Examples
# Basic usage:
#
#   <%= link_to_next_page @items, 'Next Page' %>
#
# Ajax:
#
#   <%= link_to_next_page @items, 'Next Page', :remote => true %>
#
# By default, it renders nothing if there are no more results on the next page.
# You can customize this output by passing a block.
#
#   <%= link_to_next_page @users, 'Next Page' do %>
#     <span>No More Pages</span>
#   <% end %>
def link_to_next_page(scope, name, options = {}, &block)
  params = options.delete(:params) || {}
  param_name = options.delete(:param_name) || Kaminari.config.param_name
  link_to_unless scope.last_page?, name, params.merge(param_name => (scope.current_page + 1)), options.reverse_merge(:rel => 'next') do
    block.call if block
  end
end
```

This states that when you pass a block, the block content is what is displayed when there are no more results on the next page. So it seems it does not support what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can add what you want displayed manually and then convert that code into a partial.